# Quickly reset EC on Canon 600D

Tags: canon-600d, exposure-compensation, magic-lantern

When out shooting birds, I'll often dial in several stops of EC when the bird is backlit against the sky and then forget to change the settings for a stationary bird and end up with horribly overexposed images.

Is there a way to quickly (preferably by pressing a single button) reset the exposure compensation on the 600D to 0? Turning the camera off and on doesn't work.

Answers requiring magic lantern are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 600d - not that I know of (for the simpler modes).

You can use M - the manual mode for stationary images. That has the advantage of getting you used to always quickly checking time, aperture and ISO. Since you will then switch from P to M (when going from in flight to sitting bird photo), a preset exposure compensation will not have any effect - BUT you will have to check the other values manually.

Comment: Using **M** exposure mode is the way to go here if the birds are all pretty much the same color/brightness. Just be sure to check your settings every few minutes if shooting just after sunrise or just before sunset when lighting conditions can change rapidly.